# Postgresql Docker run retain database

Tags: postgresql, docker, postgis

I docker pull from

docker pull mdillon/postgis

and use a data only volume container for Postgis.

When I create another Postgis container with the same database name and credentials and link the data only volume container

```
--volumes-from
```

to that image, all databases within that container get dropped. Is there a way / parameter to retain the data in the data only container?

Answer (score 0):

Am assuming that you're not running both containers, pointed to the container volume at the same time, you'd be sure to corrupt things pretty fast.

The only thing I can think of (I haven't been able to actually do a docker pull to test the scenario) is that the configuration files are somehow outside the container volume, which therefore gets reset when the new docker container tries to access the volume.